# Finding records sets with GROUP BY and SUM

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I'd like to do a query for every GroupID (which always come in pairs) in which both entries have a value of 1 for HasData.

```
|GroupID | HasData |
|--------|---------|
|  1     |  1      |
|  1     |  1      |
|  2     |  0      |
|  2     |  1      |
|  3     |  0      |
|  3     |  0      |
|  4     |  1      |
|  4     |  1      |
```

So the result would be:

```
1
4
```

here's what I'm trying, but I can't seem to get it right.  Whenever I do a `GROUP BY` on the GroupID then I only have access to that in the selector

```sql
SELECT GroupID
FROM Table
GROUP BY GroupID, HasData
HAVING SUM(HasData) = 2
```

But I get the following error message because HasData is acutally a bit:

```
Operand data type bit is invalid for sum operator.
```

Can I do a count of two where both records are true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just exclude those group ID's that have a record where HasData = 0.

```
select distinct a.groupID
from table1 a 
where not exists(select * from table1 b where b.HasData = 0 and b.groupID = a.groupID)
```

Comment: I'm not sure which of the three answers will preform fastest, but mapping a table to itself with two different aliases gets cool points and the the check mark.  Thanks everybody else - you all get upvotes!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `having` clause to check that all values are 1:

```
select GroupId
from table
group by GroupId
having sum(cast(HasData as int)) = 2
```

That is, simply remove the `HasData` column from the `group by` columns and then check on it.

Answer (score 1):

One more option

```
SELECT GroupID
FROM table
WHERE HasData <> 0
GROUP BY GroupID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```